# How to access specific Model fields in template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have a `ModelForm` in `views.py`: `a_form = MyModelForm(request.POST or None)`

My `ModelForm` has many fields: `field1,field2,field3` plus many more

How do I access only certain fields (lets say `field2` and `field3`) in a loop in a template?

I tried:

```
#template.html
<label>Example: </label>
    {% for text in fields %}
    #Hoping to get the a_form.field2 and a_form.field3 checkboxes with "text" as the label
        <label>{{text|return_var}}{{text}</label>
    {% endfor %}

#views.py
fields = ['field2', 'field3']
return render(request, 'template.html', {'a_form':a_form,"fields":fields)

#forms.py
@register.filter
def return_var(text):
    return "a_form." + text
```

but that only gave me `a_form.field2field2` `a_form.field3field3` as text on my page and not the checkbox with label like I wanted.

Comment: what is you purpose of hide fields? You want to hide them from user and fill by yourself or what?

Comment: My model has many fields. Field1 is a CharField with choices so I am accessing that in a different part of the template. Field2-Field8 are BooleanFields and I would like to access them in their own for loop. Field8-Field20 are also Boolean fields but I would like to access them in their own for loop too as they have different attributes and are in a different div of the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access fields using dots in your template.html:

```
<form>
    {%csrf_token%}
    <label for="{{ a_form.field1.id_for_label }}">Your field1:</label>
    {{ a_form.field1 }}
    ....
</form>
```

Read this section in django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/

UPDATE:

```
{% for field in a_form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
            <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Edit your form like this:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = YourModel
       fields = ('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
```

Also if you want to have all fields in your template, but hide some of them you can hide some of your fields using this:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = YourModel
       fields = ('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
       widgets = {
        'hidden_field4': forms.HiddenInput(),
       }
```

And after this you can loop over your hidden fields or/and visible fields:

```
{% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
{{ hidden }}
{% endfor %}
{# Include the visible fields #}
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

***FINAL***

To group your fileds like you said in comments you can do this:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = YourModel

    def field2to8(self):
        return [field for field in self if not field.is_hidden
           and field.name in ('field2', ..., 'field8')]

    def field8to20(self):
        return [field for field in self if not field.is_hidden
           and field.name in ('field8', ..., 'field20')]
```

And after this add in your template:

```
{% for field in form.field2to8 %}
    {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
    <span class="help-block">{{ field.help_text }}</span>
{% endfor %}
{% for field in form.field8to20 %}
    {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
    <span class="help-block">{{ field.help_text }}</span>                             
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this using a loop? I have many fields I want to access and want my code to be DRY

Comment: Sorry. Like stated in my original question, I would like to use the for loop to access the fields, but only access certain fields. I believe your updated solutions will access all fields in the form. Would I add an "if field is in list_of_wanted_fields"?

Comment: That looks like what I am trying to do! Thank you! Sorry for the poor explanation; I am rather new to Django.